# -0 was not expected at this time BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a fight scene in an rpg game but I keep receiving this error when I run the script,"-0 was not expected at this time." im not sure what is wrong with it. I've been searching for about an hour and I cant seem to find something that works. The script for the sceen is as follows,

```
:ATTACK
SET NUM=%RANDOM:~-2%
IF %NUM% GTR %STR% GOTO ATTACK
IF %NUM% LSS 0 GOTO ATTACK
CLS
ECHO YOU TAKE %NUM% HEALTH FROM 
ECHO THE ENEMY
PAUSE>NUL
REM the problem is these line of code Its probably is the last line but I'm
REM thinking that V this single line is fine but you can never be too sure
SET /a ENHEALTH=%ENHEALTH% - %NUM%
SET /a EXP= %EXP% + %NUM% * 2
GOTO ENATTACK
```

If there is a typo its because I script on a crappy next book.
Its in caps its that way because that's what I prefer.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to comment out sections of the code and isolate where the problem is located, or at least insert echo statements to narrow it down. This is not a "Here's a hundred or so lines of code that has this error. Fix it for me" site.

Comment: @dogman - I agree with Ken that you should pare this down before asking others for help. Have you tried running with ECHO ON?

Comment: no I haven't thought of that ill try it real quick, no it didn't help

Comment: You are using the variable STR without ever assigning a value to it. And ENATTACK is not a label... maybe a typo?

Comment: When you use `set /a`, set assumes that any text is a variable name and you don't have to use the % signs. So `SET /a ENHEALTH=%ENHEALTH% - %NUM%` can be written as `SET /a ENHEALTH=ENHEALTH - NUM`   I raise this issue as undefined variables can lead to unexpected errors in the set /a statements.

Comment: @RGuggisberd  the variable is set just not there, this isn't the full script so the player stats are not shown AKA  STR. yes ENATTACK is a label but I've shortened this down to where the problem I'm having is

Comment: @ScottC I tried that but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Consider `SET NUM=%RANDOM:~-2%`, which sets `num` to the last 2 characters of a random number. There is a possibility that `num` is then set to `08` or `09`, so `SET /a EXP= %EXP% + %NUM% * 2` will see a leading zero on `num` and object since it assumes that a leading zero indicates an octal number. It will however generate a `invalid number` message, not that reported. Please display and report the values of `exp` and `num` before the suspect `set/a` otherwise we seem to be generating a guessing game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is within the area of the file you've narrowed this down to. Wherever you are doing calculations, ensure that that you are actually using `set /a var=other - val`.  Looking at your original post, this isn't the case everywhere.

Your error message suggests that one of the variables is containing `-0` and you're using it in an if statement. e.g. `num=5 -0` and `if %num% equ 0 ...`

Just a hint for the future, throw in a few echo statements to work out where the problem is coming from. e.g. `echo reached :attack  num is %num%  enhealth is %enhealth%`